# NodeJS Express Passport multiple files

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to use passport in an Express app but getting a bit stuck trying to reference my passport strategies when my APIs/routing handlers are defined in multiple files.

I have a structure like:

- app.js
- routes\users.js
- routes\food.js

I set up the passport initialisation and define my passport strategies in app.js but then in my users.js and food.js I want to define APIs that use these strategies to protect my APIs. I cannot figure how to to reference the code I already created in those separate files.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Don´t know if this helps, if setup passport on this project:
https://github.com/Scarysize/alternativfeiern_app
Check out `server.js` and `routes/`

Comment: @C. Woza did you mange to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

use a middlewares function that authenticates every request to api.

```
function middleware(req,res,next){
   if(req.session && req.session.user){
      next();
   }else{ 
      return res.json({
         response:"login"
      })
   }
}

route.get('/', middleware , function(){
      //rest of the code
});

route.post('/', middleware , function(){
      //rest of the code
});
```